# I am getting this Error: could not find function "%>%"

Tags: r

R is not recognizing the pipe function, even though I have dplyr installed. Everything I have found online has said to install dpylr, but that does not help my case at all.

Here is my chunk of code:

```
factor_vars <- small_vdem %>% 
            mutate(
            democracy = factor(e_boix_regime, 
               labels = c("Autocracy", "Democracy")), # levels used when coding nomial variable to factor
            conflict =  factor(e_civil_war, 
              labels = c("Peace", "War")), #labels used when recoding quantitative variable to factor
            gdp_grow = factor(if_else(small_vdem$e_migdpgro > mean(small_vdem$e_migdpgro), "High", "Low")
              ))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To install a package and to load it in a R session are not the same. Have you ran `library(dplyr)` at the beginning of the script?

Comment: Thanks! I just ran the library. Now it recognizes the pipe function but does not recognize "Mutate". Any thoughts on why this might be the case?

Comment: You can use `dplyr::mutate`.

Comment: `mutate` has a lower case m and R is case sensitive.

Comment: You can use `dplyr::mutate` like @BappaDas says but it shouldn't be necessary, if the package is loaded `mutate` alone should do ti. Try restarting R.

Comment: Also, in `factor(if_else(small_vdem$e_migdpgro etc`, remove `small_vdem$` from the entire line (two occurrences).